# TYPO3 extension - foreign domain class cannot be identified by property mapper

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I'm having a form in the frontend which creates an object of the model `Question`. Each question needs to be assigned one `Category`, which is selected in the form (via `<f:form.select>`) and then submitted like so:

```
tx_qa_questionform[question][category] = 1
```

basically submitting the `Category`'s UID. After submitting the form I get an exception though:

```
#1297759968 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception
Exception while property mapping at property path "category": Could not find a suitable type converter for "Category" because no such class or interface exists.
```

So it seems that the `PropertyMapper` can't identify the domain `Category` although being defined within the extension. Shouldn't this happen by itself? Or is there any configuration I missed to set up?

`Model/Question.php`

```
namespace Vendor\QA\Domain\Model;

class Question extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * @var Category $category
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    protected $name = '';

    /**
     * @var string $mail
     */
    protected $mail = '';

    /**
     * @var string $content
     */
    protected $content = '';

    public function __construct(Category $category, string $name, string $mail, string $content) {
        $this->setCategory($category);
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setMail($mail);
        $this->setContent($content);
    }

    public function setCategory(Category $category): void {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory(): Category {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): void {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): void {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }

    public function getMail(): string {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): void {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getContent(): string {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

`Model/Category.php`

```
namespace Vendor\QA\Domain\Model;

class Category extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    protected $name;

    public function __construct(string $name) {
        $this->setName($name);
    }

    public function setName(string $name): void {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

`Controller/FrontendController.php`

```
namespace Vendor\QA\Controller;

use Vendor\QA\Domain\Model\Question;
use Vendor\QA\Domain\Repository\QuestionRepository;
use Vendor\QA\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository;

class FrontendController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    private $questionRepository;
    private $categoryRepository;

    public function injectQuestionRepository(QuestionRepository $questionRepository) {
        $this->questionRepository = $questionRepository;
    }

    public function injectCategoryRepository(CategoryRepository $categoryRepository) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    public function formAction() {
        $categories = $this->categoryRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('categories', $categories);
        $this->view->assign('newQuestion', null);
    }

    public function createQuestionAction(Question $question) {
        $this->questionRepository->add($question);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably about missing namespaces. Could you show the code (and phpdoc annotations) for the action where you want that paramaters to be mapped to a property?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need @phpdoc annotations in your controller action functions. See for example the `showAction` here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/7-Controllers/1-Creating-Controllers-and-Actions.html#flow-pattern-display-a-single-domain-object

After changing phpdoc annotations, clear the system caches.

Comment: I assumed that as well, but the exception still shows up after adding annotations to the actions. `PropertyMapper` still won't find the `Category` model.

Comment: Please do not shorten class names in Extbase annotations. Use the full `\Vendor\Extension\Classname` notation.

Comment: Oh, that did the trick. I had no idea how much TYPO3 would rely on consistent doc annotations to work. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Let's say Extbase relies on it. That part of TYPO3 is overpraised and underperforming since its beginning.